# How to prevent "toggle-saving" constants in Constant-Editor of TYPO3 8?

Tags: typo3, constants, typoscript

I'd created a new Extension via Extension Builder for FE User Registration.
TYPO3 Version 8.7.7

I'd defined two constants under settings (to get these constants in extbase and fluid):

- storagePid
- memberGroup

The **constants.ts** has the following code:

```
## Custom Sub-Categories
# customsubcategory=01_Storage=LLL:EXT:rmregistration/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:extension_configuration.customSubCategories.storage
# customsubcategory=02_Groups=LLL:EXT:rmregistration/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:extension_configuration.customSubCategories.groups

plugin.tx_rmregistration {
    view {
        # cat=plugin.tx_rmregistration/file; type=string; label=Path to template root (FE)
        templateRootPath = EXT:rmregistration/Resources/Private/Templates/
        # cat=plugin.tx_rmregistration/file; type=string; label=Path to template partials (FE)
        partialRootPath = EXT:rmregistration/Resources/Private/Partials/
        # cat=plugin.tx_rmregistration/file; type=string; label=Path to template layouts (FE)
        layoutRootPath = EXT:rmregistration/Resources/Private/Layouts/
    }
    persistence {
        # cat=plugin.tx_rmregistration//a; type=string; label=Default storage PID
        storagePid =
    }
    settings {
        # cat=plugin.tx_rmregistration/01_Storage/001; type=int[0-999]; label=LLL:EXT:rmregistration/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:extension_configuration.storagePid_and_description
        storagePid =
        
        # cat=plugin.tx_rmregistration/02_Groups/011; type=int[1-999]; label=LLL:EXT:rmregistration/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:extension_configuration.groupId_and_description
        memberGroup =
    }
}
```

The **setup.ts** has the following code:

```
plugin.tx_rmregistration {
    view {
        templateRootPaths.0 = EXT:rmregistration/Resources/Private/Templates/
        templateRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_rmregistration.view.templateRootPath}
        partialRootPaths.0 = EXT:rmregistration/Resources/Private/Partials/
        partialRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_rmregistration.view.partialRootPath}
        layoutRootPaths.0 = EXT:rmregistration/Resources/Private/Layouts/
        layoutRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_rmregistration.view.layoutRootPath}
    }
    persistence {
        storagePid = {$plugin.tx_rmregistration.persistence.storagePid}
        #recursive = 1
    }
    features {
        #skipDefaultArguments = 1
        # if set to 1, the enable fields are ignored in BE context
        ignoreAllEnableFieldsInBe = 0
        # Should be on by default, but can be disabled if all action in the plugin are uncached
        requireCHashArgumentForActionArguments = 1
    }
    mvc {
        #callDefaultActionIfActionCantBeResolved = 1
    }
    settings {
        storagePid = {$plugin.tx_rmregistration.settings.storagePid}
        memberGroup = {$plugin.tx_rmregistration.settings.memberGroup}
    }
}
```

Now if i go to the **Template**-Module -> **Constant-Editor** -> **PLUGIN.TX_RMREGISTRATION** i find my two custom constants, as expected.

But if i want to change a values i got the following problem:

---

## Problem

Initial situation:

- I have one field active with a value inside.
- I have the other field with no value inside (greyed out).

[image]

Now if i click on the `edit-undo`-button (at memberGroups) and save it, the memberGroups is deactivated (greyed out), but the other field is activated now.?!

## How can i prevent this "toggle-saving" ???

---

### What i tried to fix it myself

- Clear the whole cache (fe-cache and system-cache)
- Clear the whole cache via Install-Tool
- Clear the browser cache

### What i tried to find out

- Ask the allknown master google :D
- Search the stackoverflow system
- Ask my programmer-guru (he said it could be a false-paste-problem, but i don't know where i would have pasted the false content.

---

## EDIT

I changed my `sys_templates.php` and `tt_content.php` (as you see in the comments) and i changed **constants.txt** (i removed the view part and the customsubcategories in the following code (it's the same like above).

**constants.ts**

```
plugin.tx_rmregistration {
    persistence {
        # cat=plugin.tx_rmregistration/01_Storage/a; type=string; label=LLL:EXT:rmregistration/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:extension_configuration.storagePid_and_description
        storagePid = 0
    }
    settings {
        # cat=plugin.tx_rmregistration/01_Storage/a; type=int[1-999]; label=LLL:EXT:rmregistration/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:extension_configuration.storagePid_and_description
        storagePid = 0
        
        # cat=plugin.tx_rmregistration/02_Groups/a; type=int[2-999]; label=LLL:EXT:rmregistration/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:extension_configuration.groupId_and_description
        memberGroup = 1
    }
}
```

Changes: the default values and the range of the possible input.

**Edit**: remove badwords-settings (not important for issue)

**Same issue**

## EDIT 2

It seems so, that the fail-effect (toggle) only appears in `type=int[range]` constants.

I did some test.

First I changed constants: **S & STR** constants to `type=string` and **M & T** constants to `type=int[range]` constants for debugging it.

Legend:

- [ ] greyed out
- numbers with value

Test 1:

- Before: S [ ] M 2 T 3 STR [ ]
- Set: S 1 (changing a string constant)
- After: S 1 M 2 T 3 STR [ ]
- Works: yes

Test 2:

- Before: S 1 M 2 T 3 STR [ ]
- Set: STR 3 (changing a string constant)
- After: S 1 M 2 T 3 STR 3
- Works: yes

Test 3:

- Before: S 1 M 2 T 3 STR 3
- Set: M [ ] (changing an int[range] constant)
- After: S 1 M [ ] T 3 STR 3
- Works: the first int[range]-change yes

Test 4:

- Before: S 1 M [ ] T 3 STR 3
- Set: T [ ] (try to change an int[range] constant)
- After: S 1 **M 2** T 3 STR 3
- Works: here is the toggle bug again (**marked**) M should be [ ]

Comment: To be clear about your problem: You mean your Default Storage Pid field isn't deactivated any more, but you haven't changed it? If so, could you have a look at your constants section in the sys_template and tell, if there is a line for `plugin.tx_mmregistration.settings.storagePid`?

Comment: Yes if i deactivate the memberGroup, the storagePid is active automatically.  In the sys_template is no `plugin.tx_rmregistration.settings.storagePid`. I had no sys_templates.php nor tt_content.php (because of extension builder creates only `ext_tables.php`). I migrate this to `tt_content.php` and `sys_templates.php` now, but nothing change with that issue.

Comment: Update my question with some debuginformations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tests and debugging i think i found the solution.

My TypoScript was wrong at the following point:

If i want to use an Integer with range i have to include the default value to the range, **NOT the first possible number, after default-value**.

### NOT THIS

```
# cat=plugin.tx_rmregistration/02_Groups/a; type=int[2-999]; label=LLL:EXT:rmregistration/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:extension_configuration.groupId_and_description
    memberGroup = 1
```

### BUT THAT

```
# cat=plugin.tx_rmregistration/02_Groups/a; type=int[1-999]; label=LLL:EXT:rmregistration/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:extension_configuration.groupId_and_description
    memberGroup = 1
```

## Tests after this fix

**String or Int[Range] changes are all working now in single- and mutli-changing values.**